# Nodejs remote debugging and reverse proxying

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

When debugging nodejs using attach, vscode connects to the nodejs debugger using the address specified in launch.json

However, it seems to always use "localhost" in the requests it make.

This prevents me from routing the traffic through a proxy which needs hostnames in order to route properly

Is there anyway to control the host header in vscode's requests to the nodejs debugger?

Note: I of course don't have "localhost" entered in "address" in launch.json, but instead a hostname that resolves to the ip where the nodejs debugger is listening.

Thanks

A sniffed snippet example from request vscode => nodejs debugger:

```
GET /json/version HTTP/1.1
user-agent: got (https://github.com/sindresorhus/got)
accept: application/json
host: localhost
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: close
```

Another snippet from the ws upgrade request:

```
GET /6cabf470-7eb5-4202-b11f-4355c178c8a3 HTTP/1.1
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: qDfnpxTOzSjxQfbiJcsTWQ==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
host: localhost
```

Comment: Does the debugging port bind to the loopback interface? Also maybe have a look at this: https://blog.chromium.org/2011/05/remote-debugging-with-chrome-developer.html

Comment: My nodejs application, in this case, is a program consuming a queue, so it has no endpoints or webpages.

I'm running my application inside a docker container, and my plan is to have traefik route the debugger attach requests from vscode to the container based on the vhost. Which I'm pretty sure would work, if only the requests vscode makes would send the proper host header.

Comment: For good measure, I just tested it, by letting forwarding requests to "localhost" to my container, and then debugging works as expected.

Comment: Ok. I was only asking that if the debuging port can be exposed. Glad that you have made it work at the end.

Comment: My plan is to avoid port mapping, but mapping the port onto the host does indeed also work. However, my test mentioned above with "localhost" is not a solution, since I would have to make all my docker projects receive requests for localhost.
So my problem still stands. Anybody know how to change the host header? Or does anyone know in which project I can post a feature request?

Comment: You'll definitely find some people on stack overflow who knows how to do this?

Comment: I ended up over here :-)

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/778